Need help creating react native animation
I am trying to create this animation in react native
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ramotion/react-native-circle-menu/HEAD/preview.gif
Since the library is no longer maintained it doesnt work anymore in modern expo
I was able to create the radial menu and almost the circular animation but facing some problems
My radial menu Code
//ActionButtonItem.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated, TouchableOpacity, Platform } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const iosElevation = (forIos, forAndroid) => {
  return (
    Platform.OS === "ios" && {
      shadowOffset: { width: -2, height: 4 },
      shadowColor: "#171717",
      shadowOpacity: 0.2,
      shadowRadius: 3,
    }
  );
};

export default class ActionButtonItem extends Component {
  handlePress = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevents the parent ActionButton from closing
    this.props.onPress && this.props.onPress(e);
  };

  render() {
    const offsetX = this.props.radius * Math.cos(this.props.angle);
    const offsetY = this.props.radius * Math.sin(this.props.angle);
    
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            opacity: this.props.anim,
            width: this.props.size,
            height: this.props.size,
            transform: [
              {
                translateY: this.props.anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [0, offsetY],
                }),
              },
              {
                translateX: this.props.anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [0, offsetX],
                }),
              },
              {
                rotate: this.props.anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [
                    `${this.props.startDegree}deg`,
                    `${this.props.endDegree}deg`,
                  ],
                }),
              },
              {
                scale: this.props.anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [0, 1],
                }),
              },
            ],
          },
        ]}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          activeOpacity={this.props.activeOpacity || 0.85}
          onPress={this.handlePress}
        >
          <View
            style={[
              styles.actionButton,
              {
                width: this.props.size,
                height: this.props.size,
                borderRadius: this.props.size / 2,
                backgroundColor: this.props.buttonColor,
                elevation: 15,
              },
              iosElevation(),
            ]}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

ActionButtonItem.propTypes = {
  angle: PropTypes.number,
  radius: PropTypes.number,
  buttonColor: PropTypes.string,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  startDegree: PropTypes.number,
  endDegree: PropTypes.number,
};

ActionButtonItem.defaultProps = {
  onPress: () => {},
  startDegree: 0,
  endDegree: 720,
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  actionButton: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row",
    paddingTop: 2,
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
    },
    shadowColor: "#444",
    shadowRadius: 1,
    backgroundColor: "red",
    position: "absolute",
  },
});


//ActionButton.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ActionButtonItem, { iosElevation } from "./ActionButtonItem";
import { RFPercentage } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import * as Progress from "react-native-progress";

const alignMap = {
  center: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    startDegree: 180,
    endDegree: 360,
  },

  left: {
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    startDegree: 270,
    endDegree: 360,
  },

  right: {
    alignItems: "flex-end",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    startDegree: 180,
    endDegree: 270,
  },
  radial: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    startDegree: 0,
    endDegree: 360,
  },
};

export default class ActionButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: props.active,
      anim: new Animated.Value(props.active ? 1 : 0),
    };

    this.timeout = null;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
  }

  getActionButtonStyle() {
    return [styles.actionBarItem, this.getButtonSize()];
  }

  getActionContainerStyle() {
    const { alignItems, justifyContent } = alignMap[this.props.position];
    return [
      styles.overlay,
      styles.actionContainer,
      {
        alignItems,
        justifyContent,
      },
    ];
  }
  getActionsStyle() {
    return [this.getButtonSize()];
  }

  getButtonSize() {
    return {
      width: this.props.size,
      height: this.props.size,
    };
  }

  animateButton() {
    if (this.state.active) {
      this.reset();
      return;
    }

    Animated.spring(this.state.anim, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 250,
      friction: 5,
      tension: 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();

    this.setState({ active: true });
  }

  reset() {
    Animated.spring(this.state.anim, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 250,
      friction: 5,
      tension: 100,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ active: false });
    }, 250);
  }

  renderButton() {
    return (
      <View style={this.getActionButtonStyle()}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.85}
          onLongPress={this.props.onLongPress}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.onPress();
            if (this.props.children) {
              this.animateButton();
            }
          }}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              styles.btn,
              iosElevation(),
              {
                width: this.props.size - 5,
                height: this.props.size - 5,
                elevation: RFPercentage(5),
                borderRadius: this.props.size / 2,
                backgroundColor: this.state.anim.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: [this.props.buttonColor, this.props.btnOutRange],
                }),
              },
              {
                top: 5,
                transform: [
                  {
                    scale: this.state.anim.interpolate({
                      inputRange: [0, 1],
                      outputRange: [1, this.props.outRangeScale],
                    }),
                  },
                  {
                    rotate: this.state.anim.interpolate({
                      inputRange: [0, 1],
                      outputRange: ["0deg", this.props.degrees + "deg"],
                    }),
                  },
                ],
              },
              // {backgroundColor:'red'}
            ]}
          >
            {this.renderButtonIcon()}
          </Animated.View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderButtonIcon() {
    if (this.props.icon) {
      return this.props.icon;
    }

    return (
      <Animated.Text
        style={[
          styles.btnText,
          {
            color: this.state.anim.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [
                this.props.buttonTextColor,
                this.props.btnOutRangeTxt,
              ],
            }),
          },
        ]}
      >
        +
      </Animated.Text>
    );
  }

renderActions() {
  if (!this.state.active) return null;

  const startDegree =
    this.props.startDegree || alignMap[this.props.position].startDegree;
  const endDegree =
    this.props.endDegree || alignMap[this.props.position].endDegree;
  const startRadian = (startDegree * Math.PI) / 180;
  const endRadian = (endDegree * Math.PI) / 180;

  const childrenCount = React.Children.count(this.props.children);
  let offset = 0;
  if (childrenCount !== 1) {
    offset = (endRadian - startRadian) / (childrenCount || 1);
  }

  return React.Children.map(this.props.children, (button, index) => {
    return (
      <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={this.getActionContainerStyle()}>
        <ActionButtonItem
          key={index}
          position={this.props.position}
          anim={this.state.anim}
          size={this.props.itemSize}
          radius={this.props.radius}
          angle={startRadian + index * offset}
          btnColor={this.props.btnOutRange}
          {...button.props}
          onPress={() => {
            if (this.props.autoInactive) {
              this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.reset();
              }, 200);
            }
            button.props.onPress();
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  });
}

 
  render() {
    let backdrop;
    if (this.state.active) {
      backdrop = (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          style={styles.overlay}
          onPress={() => {
            this.reset();
            this.props.onOverlayPress();
          }}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: this.props.bgColor,
              opacity: this.state.anim,
              flex: 1,
            }}
          >
            {this.props.backdrop}
          </Animated.View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={styles.overlay}>
        {backdrop}

        {this.props.children && this.renderActions()}
        <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={this.getActionContainerStyle()}>
          {this.renderButton()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

ActionButton.Item = ActionButtonItem;

ActionButton.propTypes = {
  active: PropTypes.bool,
  bgColor: PropTypes.string,
  buttonColor: PropTypes.string,
  buttonTextColor: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.number, 
  itemSize: PropTypes.number,
  autoInactive: PropTypes.bool,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  onOverlayPress: PropTypes.func,
  backdrop: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.object]),
  startDegree: PropTypes.number,
  endDegree: PropTypes.number,
  radius: PropTypes.number,
  children: PropTypes.node,
  position: PropTypes.oneOf(["left", "center", "right","radial"]),
};

ActionButton.defaultProps = {
  active: false,
  bgColor: "transparent",
  buttonColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
  buttonTextColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
  position: "center",
  outRangeScale: 1,
  autoInactive: true,
  onPress: () => {},
  onOverlayPress: () => {},
  backdrop: false,
  degrees: 135,
  size: 63,
  itemSize: 36,
  radius: 100,
  btnOutRange: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
  btnOutRangeTxt: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  actionContainer: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    // padding: 10,
  },
  actionBarItem: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
  },
  btn: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    // shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    // shadowOffset: {
    //   width: 0,
    //   height: 1,
    // },
    // shadowColor: '#444',
    // shadowRadius: 1,
  },
  btnText: {
    marginTop: -4,
    fontSize: 24,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    position: "relative",
  },
});

Giving output as
Now I want the radial animation and here is my attempt
//RadialAnimation.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Svg, { Circle } from "react-native-svg";
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedProps,
  withTiming,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  Easing,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

const AnimatedCircle = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Circle);

const RadialProgressAnimation = ({
  color = "blue",
  radius = 150,
  icon = "ios-add",
  height,
  width,
  anglez,
}) => {
  const progress = useSharedValue(0);
  const circumference = 2 * Math.PI * radius;

  useEffect(() => {
    progress.value = withTiming(1.7, {
      duration: 1400,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    });
  }, []);

  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    return {
      strokeDashoffset: circumference * (1 - progress.value),
    };
  });

  const iconStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const angle = progress.value * 360;
    return {
      transform: [
        { translateX: radius },
        { rotate: `${angle}deg` },
        { translateY: progress.value },
      ],
    };
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Svg
        height={radius * 2.5} // Adding some extra space to avoid clipping
        width={radius * 2.5}
        style={{
          transform: [{ rotate: `${anglez}deg` }],
          flex: 1,
          
        }} 
      >
        <AnimatedCircle
          cx={radius} //15 for right
          cy={radius}
          r={radius}
          fill="transparent"
          stroke={color}
          strokeWidth={100}
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeDasharray={`${circumference}, ${circumference}`}
          animatedProps={animatedProps}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
      </Svg>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          iconStyle,
          {
            position: "absolute",
            backgroundColor: "green",
            flex: 1,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Icon
          name={icon}
          size={32}
          color={"white"}
          style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: "auto",
    width: "auto",
    margin: 30,
    zIndex: 150,
  },
});

export default RadialProgressAnimation;

//Index.js
import { useState } from "react";
import React, { StyleSheet, View, useWindowDimensions } from "react-native";
import ActionButton from "@kashyap_trivedi/react-native-circular-action-menu";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import RadialProgressAnimation from "./components/RadialAnimation";
const CircleMenu = () => {
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(null);

  const handleButtonClick = (color, icon, anglez) => {
    setActiveButton({ color, icon, anglez });
    // Reset after animation (duration + a little extra)
    setTimeout(() => setActiveButton(null), 1100);
  };

  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#f3f3f3",
        position: "absolute",
        top: height / 2,
        left: width / 2,
      }}
    >
      {activeButton && (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            position: "absolute",
            zIndex: 50,
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
          }}
        >
          <RadialProgressAnimation
            color={activeButton.color}
            icon={activeButton.icon}
            anglez={activeButton.anglez}
            height={height}
            width={width}
            radius={150}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      <ActionButton
        buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)"
        radius={150}
        btnOutRange={"rgba(231,76,60,1)"}
        degrees={360}
        size={90}
        itemSize={90}
        position="radial"
        autoInactive={false}
      >
        <ActionButton.Item
          buttonColor="#9b59b6"
          title="New Task"
          onPress={() => handleButtonClick("#9b59b6", "navigate", 360)}
        >
          <Icon name="navigate" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
        </ActionButton.Item>
        <ActionButton.Item
          buttonColor="#3498db"
          title="Notifications"
          onPress={() => handleButtonClick("#3498db", "accessibility", 90)}
        >
          <Icon name="accessibility" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
        </ActionButton.Item>
        <ActionButton.Item
          buttonColor="#1abc9c"
          title="All Tasks"
          onPress={() => handleButtonClick("#1abc9c", "menu", 180)}
        >
          <Icon name="menu" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
        </ActionButton.Item>
        <ActionButton.Item
          buttonColor="#1abc9c"
          title="All ok"
          onPress={() => handleButtonClick("#1abc9c", "home", 270)}
        >
          <Icon name="home" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
        </ActionButton.Item>
      </ActionButton>
    </View>
  );
};

export default CircleMenu;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color: "white",
  },
});

Leading to this
https://imgur.com/a/aRPip7T
Now how to solve these problems in the animation
1)RadialAnimation gets clipped even on setting a higher height and width
2)Animation should start from bottom of the button
3)Button Icon should translate in the radial progress animation
